# Excel use dates as x axis, but numbers to fit regression equation

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, label, regression

I have some data that fits a linear trend over time. When I fit a regression line, I get a formula that has a negative 42000 in it. When presenting, this number may cause confusion. I would still like to keep the dates on the x-axis of the chart, but have my regression equation use numbers like 1,2,3,...instead of date values like 43013.

I tried to follow
Microsoft Office Support’s [Change axis labels in a chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-axis-labels-in-a-chart-1c32436b-fb12-450b-aefa-cc7e4584456a) article,
but changing horizontal axis labels is greyed out

This is what the chart looks like:

[image: regression line]

Comment: Excel stores dates as the number of days since 12/31/1899 (1/1/1900 = day 1).  It's been about 43,000 days since then, which is why date math and regression is showing those kinds of numbers.  You can translate the values to small numbers if you want a simpler-looking trend equation, but then the X axis won't properly reflect your dates.  (cont'd)

Comment: You can jump through hoops with tricks to use both sets of numbers and superimpose the disparate values in one chart.  Or you could just add a brief explanation of the number to your presentation and make it more educational.  Or, leave off the equation from the trend chart, or use a text box to plug in the equation based on your low number values.

Comment: Your first comment summarizes my dilemma exactly. I like the idea to your second comment, text box might be the easiest fix. What I was asking for originally is the hoops and tricks. I essentially want another column/array that corresponds 1:1 with the date values. So basically have the regression line fit to some numbered data with x values at 1,2,3 instead of 42101, 42102, 42103. Then superimpose the dates back on as the labels for the x-axis.

Comment: A potential simple solution: algebra shows that `0.9878x-42101` is equivalent to `0.9878(x-42621)`.  `42621` is 9/8/2016.  Instead of having Excel show the trendline formula, enter that manually in a textbox, but express the equation as: `y = 0.9878 * number of days since 9/8/2016`.  Then you don't need to worry about matching translated numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not clear what you’re actually asking for here. 
Since the complaint appears to be
that `42000` in your formula may cause confusion,
consider replacing it with `DATE(2014,12,27)`. 
(Your figure shows `42101`, which is `DATE(2015,4,7)`.) 
Or replace it with `DATE(2015,1,1)` (which equals `42005`)
and adjust the other constants in the formula accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this type of analysis is to use raw Microsoft Time value. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIMEVALUE-function-0b615c12-33d8-4431-bf3d-f3eb6d186645

Comment: It isn't clear how this addresses what was asked in the question.